# Angular auto deployment in azure dev ops pipeline

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Angular auto deployment in azure dev ops

When I was run pipeline I got this error.

```
FTP Upload: Agent Job
·
2 errors

21s
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.208.237.166:22 (control socket)

Ftp Upload failed.
```

We have successfully run build,release and web services as running fine, but our site/wwwroot has empty. So connect FTP connection to push dist code to site/wwwroot.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to your pipeline after `npm prod`, so there is no need in FTP Upload, it will copy `/dist` folder to the artifact, which you are going to deploy next.

So your pipeline for Angular project will contain the following steps:
[image: Pipeline]

Also make sure you select the right *Package or folder* location at Azure App Service Deploy: Angular Deployment task.